# Visual Studio Online permission: create new project

Tags: tfs, permissions, azure-devops

I searched today to the solution for the next problem: A colleague wants to add a projcet on our Visual studio online platform. For that i gave his permission "Create Project" the value "Allowed". Still he could not see the button 'new'. 
Then I added him to the Group: "Project Collection Managers", but still he can't make a new project. Anyone who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your colleague to create team projects, not projects. Only VSO owner can create team projects. You can have VSO owner to create a team project for your colleague, then your colleague will be able to connect to the team project and share his/her projects.